# What happens if I CTRL + C halfway through a cli command?

Tags: magento2, cli

So I'm setting the mode of the store to production. It's done the compilation etc. but hangs on the static content deployment. If I were to CTRL + C the command now, will the mode still be set to production and will my code still be "compiled"? I'd try, but I've been waiting 15 minutes as it is and don't want to start the process again if it turns out it reverts everything and haven't found anything in the docs

Thanks! :)